# Añadir una línea de texto en la consola a objetos dentro de un array

Tags: javascript-import

Después de conseguir un código para crear un array solamente con los usuarios que no son premium. Debo encontrar la manera de poder añadir una línea de texto en la consola a los usuarios que son premium.

```js
const users = [
    
    {username: "ppc90", age: 30, premium: false},

    {username: "lu65", age: 24, premium: true},

    {username: "maria3", age: 36, premium: false},

    {username: "abc123", age: 30, premium: false},

    {username: "sergio58", age: 30, premium: true},

];

const nopremium = users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.premium <= false
});
console.log(nopremium)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Usando filter

Puedes usar la misma técnica con filter, en lugar de chequear por false, compruebas si la condición es igual a true.

```
const premium = users.filter(user => user.premium === true);
```

## Cuidado

En tu código estás haciendo

```
user.premium <= false
```

para comprobar el estado premium en falso. `<=` (menor o igual que) no es semánticamente correcto, aunque funcione para ese caso específico. Recuerda que `false` "coherce" a 0, y `true` a 1.

La comparación correcta sería

```
user.premium === false
```

## Código ejemplo

```js
const users = [

    {username: "ppc90", age: 30, premium: false},
    
    {username: "lu65", age: 24, premium: true},
    
    {username: "maria3", age: 36, premium: false},
    
    {username: "abc123", age: 30, premium: false},
    
    {username: "sergio58", age: 30, premium: true},
    
    ];
    
const nopremium = users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.premium === false
});
const premium = users.filter(user => user.premium === true);

console.log(nopremium)
console.log(premium);
```

Comment: Muy buena tu aportación. Me gusta. Gracias

Comment: Si la respuesta te sirve la puedes marcar como correcta con el tilde a la izquierda :)

Answer (score 0):

puedes aplicar otro filter para encontrar la diferencia entre el arreglo original "users" y filtrar los que ya identificaste como "nopremium" usando tu mismo código de base, fijate la constante premium en el ejemplo:

```js
const users = [

    {username: "ppc90", age: 30, premium: false},
    
    {username: "lu65", age: 24, premium: true},
    
    {username: "maria3", age: 36, premium: false},
    
    {username: "abc123", age: 30, premium: false},
    
    {username: "sergio58", age: 30, premium: true},
    
    ];
    
const nopremium = users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.premium <= false
});

const premium = users.filter(x => !nopremium.includes(x));

console.log("usuarios no premium que ya tienes=")
console.log(nopremium)
console.log("usuarios premium=")
console.log(premium)
```

Comment: Interesante tu aportación. Gracias